# How do I control the flow of a scrapy crawler to target one page at a time?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, yield

I'm trying to extract information from a simple online gallery. The gallery structure is like: (many)[pages] >containing many> [albums] >contaning many> [photos].

I set up the following spider to get the title and photos for each album on all pages (just the URLs for now):

```
from scrapy import Spider, Request

class Crawler(Spider):
name = 'myCrawler'

start_urls = [
    'https://samplesite.com'
]


def parse(self, response):

    for album in response.xpath('//a[@class="album"]/@href').extract():
        yield response.follow(album, callback=self.parse_album)

    next_page = response.xpath('//a[@class="next"]/@href').extract_first()
    if next_page is not None:
        yield response.follow(next_page, callback=self.parse)


def parse_album(self, response):

    yield {
        'Title' : response.xpath('//div[@id="album-title"]/h1/text()').extract(),
    }

for image in response.xpath('//div[@class="thumbnail"]//a[@class="thumb"]/@href').extract():
        yield response.follow(image, callback=self.parse_image)

def parse_image(self, response):
    yield { IMAGE : response.xpath('/html/body/div[@id="photo"]/a/img/@src').extract() }
```

This gives me the data I want but not in any order. I want to get the title and all photos of a particular album before moving to the next one, then, after every album on that page is done, move to the next page. How can this be done?

Comment: You have to provide sample desired output first and what actually you are getting in output. But at first, looking at your code, I think the way you are using `yield` with `Title` and `Image` is itself somewhat not correct. You have to use `meta` property of requests object to pass data through as many as scrapy requests.

Comment: May I ask you why do you need order and scrap album one by one? In your case, I would propose to try to make some unique id per each album and in the pipeline or after crawler will be done sort all in album/page order

Comment: The whole point of scrapy is the asynchronous requests. If you want one at a time you should use something else.